# How to use silverlight control in html5 application

Tags: c#, html, silverlight

We have an existing silverlight control. now we want to use this control in one of our HTML5 projects.

Is this possible, to use silverlight control inside HTML5 page?

Answer (score 1):

From the official Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc189089(v=vs.95).aspx), you should use this piece of HTML:

`<object width="300" height="300"
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" >
    <param name="source" value="NAME_OF_YOUR_SILVELIGHT_FILE.xap"/>
</object>`

Comment: Thanks fot the reply. Here could you please help me in understanding that what is the control name that has been used? I can only see the xap name which can contain many controls.

Comment: Each Silverlight application should be contained in a separate XAP file. You should put that file in the HTML code above and then manage which control is shown from Silverlight-side.